# AWS Quicksight automatic refresh for visuals

Tags: amazon-web-services, refresh, visualization, amazon-quicksight, amazon-athena

i know... i found this question a couple of times on Google but they might be outdated as AWS continuously delivers updates on Quicksight.

I have linked Athena to my SQL-based Quicksight dataset. When there is new data in my dynamoDB i want to see it near-realtime in Quicksight. The dynamo can be updated on demand or on a scheduled basis.

As of now, i have to click in the Analysis-view on 'refresh' of the corresponding visual to refresh it. Is it possible to automatically refresh it? I mean... If i use PowerBI, Tableau or anything else, it automatically updates the visuals... At least if I click on the refresh-button of the page.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS Quicksight for SPICE datasets, there is an option to refresh the dataset on the edit dataset page. Once you click on refresh the visuals/graphs automatically get refreshed.
AWS has also introduced a new auto-refresh option (Schedule refresh) through which you can schedule your refreshes from every 15min to monthly refreshes.

Quicksight has two types of refreshes: Full refresh and incremental refresh

- In full refresh, the data gets deleted completely at the scheduled time and new data gets appended to the same table.
- For an incremental refresh, once you set a window (the interval at which you want to check for new data), Quicksight will check for new data in the scheduled window and appends data to the existing dataset
  Through both of these ways the visuals get updated automatically